# Is "want" an action verb?

Tags: verbs

I'm curious whether "want" is classified as an "action verb".

When I think about it, *to want something* doesn't really show an action. Nobody is doing anything when they want something, it's more of a state of being.

If it's not an "action verb", what kind of verb is it?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess *want* has been found wanting then?

Comment: There are a lot of kinds of "action verbs"; that's not a simple category. One test is whether they can occur with Action _do_ in a _Wh_-cleft sentence, like _What he did was drive off a cliff_ (which shows that _drive_ is an action verb). But I don't think that *_What he did was want more chocolate_ sounds terribly grammatical; we'd be more likely to say _What he did was get/eat/make/drink more chocolate_, since those are all active. Syntactic tests are best for telling you these things.

Comment: @JohnLawler But _All he did was want to help_ sounds natural.

Comment: That's not action _do_; that's just _do_-support. Try an imperative: *_Go over and want to help them!_

Comment: @JohnLawler, can you elaborate on your previous comment? I've read *do*-support is used for Negation and Question-formation; how is it being used there? And, what does the unacceptability of the VP "want to help them" in the imperative suggest?

Comment: It's used for those, and for many other constructions. In the _All_-Cleft you presented, the _do_ is inserted as part of the transformation from the base sentence of _He wanted to help_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> There are a lot of kinds of "action verbs"; that's not a simple category. One test is whether they can occur with Action *do* in a *Wh*-cleft sentence, like *What he did was drive off a cliff* (which shows that *drive* is an action verb). But I don't think that **What he did was want more chocolate* sounds terribly grammatical; we'd be more likely to say *What he did was get/eat/make/drink more chocolate*, since those are all active. Syntactic tests are best for telling you these things.